# how to validate element is angular js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, validation

I make a view from json object. I am able to make take now I need to valid element on keyup event and blur event. So I googled it and find this tutorial 
http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/angularjs-form-validation

I try to implement this in my demo, but when I used this:

```
<p ng-show="userForm.name.$invalid && !userForm.name.$pristine"
    class="help-block">`Your name is required.</p>
```

This break my view can you please tell me how to validate thing in angular if there is no form?

Here is my plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/we1QHuDuCOOR4tDAk6yv?p=preview

```
  <script>
    function Controller($scope) {
    $scope.outputs = {};
    $scope.inputs = [{
        type: "email",
        name: "email",
        required:true
    }, {
        type: "text",
        name: "name",
    }, {
        type: "number",
        name: "phonenumber",
    }, {
        type: "checkbox",
        name: "whant to check",
    },
    {
        type: "url",
        name: "server Url",
    }];

}
  </script>
```

Comment: You won't be able to use angular's form validation without a form. You'd have to hook into `ng-change` or use a `$watch` in your controller.

Comment: can you change my plunker ..give example..can I change into form ?

Comment: is there any way to change this on form  or another way to validate ?

Comment: @irani do you have any solution

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to use [ng-form](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngForm) like

```
        <div ng-switch="input.type" ng-form="myfrm">
            <div ng-switch-when="text">
                <input type="text" ng-model="outputs[input.name]"/>
            </div>
            <div ng-switch-when="email">
                <input type="email" ng-model="outputs[input.name]" name="input" ng-required="input.required">
                <span ng-if="myfrm.input.$invalid">Please enter a valid email</span>
            </div>
            <div ng-switch-when="number">
                <input type="number" ng-model="outputs[input.name]"/>
            </div>
            <div ng-switch-when="url">
                <input type="number" ng-model="outputs[input.name]"/>
            </div>
            <div ng-switch-when="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="outputs[input.name]" ng-checked="outputs[input.name]" value="outputs[input.name]"/>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/19xOkXDsUbTuUbbMiTJW?p=preview)

Comment: I need to add validate on blur as well as key up and key down ?

Comment: @user3665790 see http://plnkr.co/edit/JleucNFICr9OXl7mb4ch?p=preview - `input` in `myfrm.input.$invalid` is the name of the input filed

Comment: you give good solution there is issue in that ..red box appear before writing .when user press submit it should come that time(but there is submit button) .when user type some thing then it give invalid email or valid mail while typing or moving focus one field to another

Comment: @user3665790 for now I don't have a better solution... but if you can post a new question some other guys might be able to help you(since you marked this answer as accepted more people may not spent more time in this again)

Comment: the Question is why red border display when I run application.I need when user run application it not display .It only display when move focus one field to anothet

Comment: @user3665790 it is not showing a red border for me?

Comment: check on firefox..there is message return it after application launch.it should come when user move one field to another